# Suggested way to embed or include an article as an appendix within another book?

Tags: include

I have made an scientific article using LuaTeX because I need to publish it on a journal. It's already completely written and laid out.
Now, I also need to write my thesis and include the former article as one of the appendices.

The problem is they use different styles (fonts, sizes, margins, line spacing, article vs twosided book...) and they have each their own structure (index, chapters, abstract...).

How can I embed one document into the other one keeping each own with its style and structure?

- If I just use an *include* with the article source code, without its preamble, it will compile everything using my thesis options and loose the article original style.
- If I try to include the article source code with all the preamble and options it will produce an error because its incompatible.
- I can also try to include the already compiled article as a pdf.
- Finally I can just create both pdf files separatelly and merge them with an external program, but it's going to be more difficult to number the pages.

What is the suggested way to do it?
I would like to get a single page numbering for everything.
And I'm hesitating about keeping also (simultaneously) the numbering of the article, otherwise I would need to change its index.

I would like to get something like this:

```
front page
title
toc
chapter
section
 subsection
section
 subsection
references
appendix1 (data)
appendix2 (article)
  title
  section
  subsection
  section
  subsection
  references
appendix3 (code)
```

Getting a unique sequential page numbering.

Comment: I have done this with the `pdfpages` package, which lets you include multi-page PDFs, but still provides some control over borders, headers, footers, and so on.

Comment: All of the \includegraphics options are supported by pdfpages, including trim and clip (see page 8).  So you can remove the existing page numbers and headers instead of shrinking a whole page into the text area.

Comment: So you are suggesting to embed the already compiled pdf file instead of including the code?

Comment: It would be easier, especially if the page size is different..  Going over the pdfpages options, there doesn't seem to be one to use the existing text area.  One can always use` \includegraphics[page=1,width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{...}` for page=2, page=3 ... .

Comment: Will the result have editable text or ir will everything be embedded as an image?

Comment: It is only editable in the sense that you can clip off the article's margins, if so desired.  The \includegrpahics version puts the entire article page into the text area of your thesis and uses the thesis headers and footers.

Comment: How could I do it including the source coude of the article, keeping its substructure? (but avoiding figure and table name conflicts)